# Rearranging sql query table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

when I have a sql query (after pivot etc) which look like this

```
ID    Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4
Name1 N1V1     N1V2     N1V3     N1V4
Name2 N2V1     N2V2     N2V3     N2V4
```

And this table should be projected into this  (for each native row creating 2 new rows):

```
ID    Value1/2  Value3/4
Name1  N1V1      N1V3
Name1  N1V2      N1V4
Name2  N2V1      N2V3
Name2  N2V2      N2V4
```

How shall I do this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Kind regards, Markus

Comment: Why would N1V1 go with N1V3 and not with N1V4 etc?

Answer (score 0):

There are too few input data to guess the result desired. Are all values unique? Do you need duplicates?
But as a first approach, try to use this one:

```
SELECT id, value1 as value_1_2, value3 as value_3_4 
FROM table1 
union all
SELECT id, value2, value4 FROM table1
order by 1;
```